# canvas x, y value on a reponsive changing page with screen size

Tags: canvas, responsive

I am trying to get the x, y coordinates from two different canvases on one page which can change position with responsive screen resizing.

The test page looks like the picture below:
[image]

With my current code, when I click on either of the black dots I get the correct x, y coordinates for the canvas I clicked within.

However, if the page is resized and the right canvas drops below the left canvas, when I click on the now lower canvas black dot the Y value is miles out and I can't work out a way around this.

The code is shown below which can be run in full screen with the response resizing.

My goal is to know when the black dot has been clicked on and what canvas this event happened within. It must be able to do this with the page resizing on different screens

Just to clarify the Y coordinates of canvas 2 top line is 15. If I resize and canvas 2 drops below canvas 1 the y becomes approx 323 on the top line but I need it to stay at the same value as it was before resizing

```js
function circle (name, setTemp, temp){
  c=document.getElementById(name);
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = 200;
  c.height = 300;
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,170,5,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
}
circle ('den');
circle ('wc');
var den=document.getElementById('den');
den.addEventListener('mousedown',denClicked, false);
function denClicked(event){
    c=document.getElementById('den');
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = event.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = event.pageY;
  console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
}
var wc=document.getElementById('wc');
wc.addEventListener('mousedown',wcClicked, false);
function wcClicked(event){
    c=document.getElementById('wc');
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = event.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = event.pageY;
  console.log(rect);
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
/* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
         <div><canvas id="den"></canvas> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <div><canvas id="wc"></canvas> </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div><script src="canvas.js"></script> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have it working. probably better way to do this but at the moment its working when page is resized.

under the click function I get the page height which may have been resized hence the reason for doing this under the click function.
If the width of the page has gone below the width in css to change page layout, an if function will increase a compensator to take away from the Y axis to give the correct coordinates.

So far, its working ok, will need to test this more with 4 canvases in a row and on different screen sizes

```
 var Ycompensator = 0;
function circle (name, setTemp, temp){
  c=document.getElementById(name);
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = 200;
  c.height = 300;
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,170,5,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
}
circle ('den');
circle ('wc');
var den=document.getElementById('den');
den.addEventListener('mousedown',denClicked, false);
function denClicked(event){
    c=document.getElementById('den');
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = event.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = event.pageY - rect.top;
  console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
}
var wc=document.getElementById('wc');
wc.addEventListener('mousedown',wcClicked, false);
function wcClicked(event){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w < 768){
      Ycompensator = 324;
    }
    c=document.getElementById('wc');
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = event.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = event.pageY - Ycompensator;
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
}
```